# Is it secure to explicitly setting session IDs in HTTP Requests?

Tags: php, security, session

I have my account system at `accounts.example.com`.

When a user logged in at `accounts.example.com`, the session ID will be saved on a cookie which is available on `.example.com` (In all subdomains)

`subdomain.example.com` is in another server and it doesn't have access to session data and database of the accounts system. How I check if the user is logged in is that I get the session ID (as it is available in all the subdomains). Then, I send an HTTP request to the accounts server with the session id and a password (A password that secures HTTP requests).

The HTTP request from `subdomain.example.com` is as follows.

```php
$sessionId = $_COOKIE[$sessionCookieName];
$post = http_build_query(
    array (
        'http_secret' => AUTH_HTTP_SECRET,
        'session_id' => $sessionId
    )
);

$opts = array('http' => 
    array (
        'method' => 'POST',
        'user_agent' => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
        'content' => $post
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$url = 'https://account.example.com/check-login';
$response = @file_get_contents($url , false, $context);
```

So, an HTTP request will be sent to `accounts.example.com/check-login`.

`check-login.php` at `accounts.example.com` is as follows.

```php
$httpSecret = $_POST['http_secret'];
// if it is from an invalid client
if  ($httpSecret !== HTTP_SECRET) {
    throw new Exception('HTTP Error');
}

$sessionId = $_POST['session_id'];

# set the session ID
session_id($sessionId);

# then, I get the session data and checks if the user is logged in
```

If the user is logged in I return the account-related data to `subdomain.example.com`.

Is this approach is good or bad?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did subdomain.example.com get the password? `Then I get session data` How? You just said you don't have access to session data because the subdomain is on another server?

Comment: I meant, I send a password: it is a password to secure server HTTP request. It is not the user's password. It is just to validate HTTP requests. Got it?

Comment: Understood. So how do you "get session data"? Does that part happen on the other server, and you return the data in the response? It would help if you marked what happens where

Comment: How does a user log out?

Comment: I edited my answer, and, user can logout from `accounts.example.com/logout`. It will remove all the session data saved in the accounts server. So, the next HTTP request will return false to the question "is logged in?"

Answer (score -1):

There is no security flaw in it. That is one of the reasons you have the function in the first place.

And if you want your code reviewed, try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Downvote reason: answer doesn't provide sufficient information and is vague. Why would one periodically rotate id's is ambiguous, along with `configured properly`. It leaves too much to assumption, it should be a comment.

Comment: Can you please explain more? I think I have configured options correctly. But, if you tell exactly what they are, I can exactly check them with mine. Thanks.

Comment: I think knowing how to configure a session is out of this contest. and from the question since php is not generating the session id for he/she, relying on php to invalidate them on expire doesn't sound ideal

Comment: When the user logs in, PHP generates the session ID. And, I don't understand your point.

Comment: @Mjh yeah you are right. there is no need for rotation.

Comment: @SupunKavinda your approach is not bad.

Comment: @ChrysUgwu okay. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score -2):

No, it is not secure, you should use HTTPS for this.

Comment: I don't think it's the case. I use HTTPs for inter-server communication. It is a simple thing I think.